# If $B_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k$, then $\bar{B}_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory

I don't get the parts in blue, can you help me please? Also any observation about anything would be appreciated.

If $B_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k$ then $\bar{B}_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$

By hypothesis, we have that $B_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k$, so $\color{Blue}{\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k\subseteq \bar{B}_m}$ and $A_k\subseteq B_m$, then $\bar{A}_k\subseteq \bar{B}_m$ and so:

$\implies \bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k\subseteq \bar{B}_m$

And because $A_k\subseteq \bar{A}_k$, by hyp. $\implies \bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$, then:

$\implies \color{Blue}{B_m\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k}$

And if we take the closure on both sides, we get:

$\bar{B}_m\subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k}$

$\bar{B}_m\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$

So far we got $\bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k\subseteq \bar{B}_m$ and $\bar{B}_m\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$, therefore, $\bar{B}_m=\bigcup_{k=1}^m \bar{A}_k$

Comment: These both follow from the fact that $C\subseteq\bar{C}$.